# How can I force the base constructor to be called in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, constructor, c#-2.0

I have a BasePage class which all other pages derive from:

```
public class BasePage
```

This BasePage has a constructor which contains code which must always run:

```
public BasePage()
{
    // Important code here
}
```

I want to force derived classes to call the base constructor, like so:

```
public MyPage
    : base()
{
    // Page specific code here
}
```

**How can I enforce this (preferably at compile time)?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The base constructor will always be called at some point. If you call `this(...)` instead of `base(...)` then that calls into another constructor in the same class - which again will have to either call yet another sibling constructor or a parent constructor. Sooner or later you will always get to a constructor which either calls `base(...)` explicitly or implicitly calls a parameterless constructor of the base class.

See [this article](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/constructors.html) for more about constructor chaining, including the execution points of the various bits (such as variable initializers).

Answer (score 12):

The base class constructor taking no arguments is automatically run if you don't call any other base class constructor taking arguments explicitly.

Comment: So does that mean I can remove the line containing : base()?

Answer (score 3):

The base class constructor is always called, even if you don't call it explicitly. So you don't need to do any extra work to make sure that happens.

Answer (score 2):

One of the base constructors always needs to be called, and the default one is called when the base constructor is not explicitly stated.

Edit: rephrased for clarity.